# Starting the mule without mule-config.xml and to load the mule-config programatically

Tags: mule

I am having a requirement like interacting the mules from different machines.I used the tcp inbound endpoint it is working perfectly if I configure everything in the mule-config.xml.Now my problem is i dont want to use the mule-config.xml but I want to load it programmatically.if any one have the solution pls update..
Thask.

Comment: Why you don't want to use the standard? What do you mean by loading programmatically? Are you planning to run Mule embedded in a different application?

Comment: Programatically means, instead of reading from the mule-config.xml,I want to create the connectors,endpoints using the mule classes.I found some code for vm endpoints, but I need to write for TCP.if you have any idea pls help me..

Comment: I have asked "why" :)

Comment: Its because I am having more than 30 components running in tomcat.Now I am having a requirements like I want to run the components separately and they should communicate each other.So i had chosen the mule, Now why I am not using the mule-connfig.xml is already I am loading all these compoenents using a xml file where I can configure  all the  IPaddress and the port of the other machines.SO i dont need one more mule-config.xml to configure these parameters..

Comment: Take a look into this: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Embedding+Mule+in+a+Java+Application+or+Webapp

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using Mule is that you can configure your flows simplistically, rather than writing complex code yourself. Having said that you can programmatically configure endpoints provided they are

1. outbound endpoints.
2. OR you using  [mulerequester:request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636573/unable-to-create-dynamic-file-inbound-endpoint-in-mule)

You cannot programmatically configure inbound endpoint.