# How can I get spring property in flow?

Tags: spring, mule

I work with Mule. And I have spring bean

```
<spring:bean id="`MyPropertiesSaver`" name="MyPropertiesSaver" class="MyPropertiesSaver">
        <spring:property name="prop_name" value="${PROP_VALUE}"/>
    </spring:bean>
```

Also I work with file in flow

```
<flow name="Handler" doc:name="Handler">
    <file:inbound-endpoint `path="${PROP_VALUE}"` moveToPattern="#[header:originalFilename].txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    ...
</flow>
```

So I get PROP_VALUE from system variables. I want to change path of file while programm is running. I change `prop_name` of class `MyPropertiesSaver` using MX4J. But `path="${PROP_VALUE}"` does not change. That's why I want to get `prop_name` from `MyPropertiesSaver`. Somthing like this

```
path="MyPropertiesSaver.prop_name"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the [file message receiver](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/file/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/file/FileMessageReceiver.java) to allow to externally set of the fileDir and disconnect-connect when this happens. Then in your connector use a [service-override](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+a+Transport#ConfiguringaTransport-overrides) to use that customised message receiver.

Comment: I overrided `basicListFiles(readDirectory, discoveredFiles)`. Now instead of `readDirectory` I use my own path what I can change.

Answer (score 1):

Having a Dynamic Endpoint for File Inbound is not possible.
File Inbound should know where to look for when the flow is started.

If your usecase demands a dynamic file location and reading you can try the workaround with Mule Requester module.

Read throubh the following link for more details.

[Unable to create dynamic file inbound endpoint in mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636573/unable-to-create-dynamic-file-inbound-endpoint-in-mule)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since we're using a spring property here, the value is available when the flow is started.

Comment: I see that the OP wants to change the path after the flow is started, so subsequent changes to this property would require a dynamic value.  Using the requester module is probably your best bet.